# Avoid run animation starting while character is still falling

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I've got a jump animation but i forgot to make a seperate 'falling' animation (and i've lost the original blender files so I can't go back and make one). At the moment, my character jumps and then the run aniamtion starts as soon as the jump is complete, so it starts running mid air.

What's the best way of solving this?

Can I pause the animation mid way through the jump?

I'm using c#.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can pause the animation when the player is in the air with `Animator.enabled = false;` or `Animator.StopPlayback();` then detect when the player is touching the floor with collider and `enable` your animation again.